# Junit Asserting failed HTTP post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, junit, assert

I have an HTTPClient test for my spring boot app. I have a class that throws an exception if the a POST request to the server is in a string 2048 bytes or over.

```
@Component
 public class ApplicationRequestSizeLimitFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getContentLength());
        if (request.getContentLengthLong() >= 2048) {
            throw new IOException("Request content exceeded limit of 2048 bytes");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }


}
```

I created a unit test for it but I am not sure how I can write an assert statement to check if it fails to post the request.

Right now I have this so far in my test class

```
@Test
    public void testSize() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        Random r = new Random(123);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
            s += r.nextInt(2);
        String result = Request.Post(mockAddress)
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(s, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

    }
```

This test fails which is what I want but I want to create an assert so it passes (assert that it fails the http response due to being over the byte limit).

Comment: Do you get an exception ? `@Test` has an argument to assert that an exception was thrown, e.g `@Test(expected = IOException.class)` .

Comment: Yes its supposed to give an exception with the error message. This worked, thank you. Please write this as an answer so I can accept and give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Test` has an argument to assert that a particular exception gets thrown, you could write your test like e.g :

```
    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testSize() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can surround the failing part with a try/catch, and call fail() at the end of the try block. If an exception is thrown, the fail() instruction should not be reached, and your test should pass.

Comment: I prefer this method as you can then check the exception itself to makes sure it contains failure messages that you might be expecting.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways you can achieve that:

1) Use `@Test(expected = ....`) annotation where you provide class of exception you want to check.

```java
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void test() {
  //... your test logic
}
```

This is not a recommended way of exception testing unless your test is really really small and does one thing only. Otherwise, you may get an `IOException` thrown but you won't be sure which part of test code exactly caused it.

2) Use `@Rule` annotation with `ExpectedException` class:

```java
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testExpectedException() {
    exceptionRule.expect(IOException.class);
    exceptionRule.expectMessage("Request too big.");
//... rest of your test logic here
}
```

Please note that `exceptionRule` has to be **public**.

3) And last one, quite old-fashioned way:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
  try {
    // your test logic
    fail(); // if we get to that point it means that exception was not thrown, therefore test should fail.
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // if we get here, test is successfull and code seems to be ok.
  }
}
```

It's an old fashioned way that adds some unnecessary code to your test that is supposed to be clean.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, not already presented in these answers, and is my personal preference. **assertThatThrownBy**

in your case

```
@Test
public void testSizeException(){
  assertThatThrownBy(()-> Request.Post(mockAddress)
                  .connectTimeout(2000)
                  .socketTimeout(2000)
                  .bodyString(s, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                  .execute().returnContent().asString())
                  .isInstanceOf(IOException.class)
                  .hasMessageContaining("Request content exceeded limit of 2048 
  bytes");
}
```

*Disclaimer, above code written directly into SO editor